# Uniform continuity and maximum and minimum with a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, uniform-continuity, extreme-value-theorem

Problem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, so that for every $\epsilon >0$, there exits a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n-K$.

Show that:

**(i)** $f$ takes on $\mathbb{R}^n$ a global maximum and minimum.

**(ii)** $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Questions/Issues:

Currently struggling to figure out the beginning of the proof. For what I know, there are compact sets that restricts $f$ to a $\epsilon$. So from what I know intuitively, that there is at least a point, at which $f$ is bounded to a compact set.

For the uniform continuity, I currently have no idea, where the beginning is to solve that part of the problem.

Thanks for the replies in advance.

Comment: Do you know that continuous functions have a maximum and a minimum on every compact set? Use that, and that $f$ can be made arbitrarily small on the complement of a compact set.

Comment: I want to ask them, how that would essentially look like, the arbitrarily small thing. I do not know much about that pretty much. Thanks for the reply, it really helped.

Comment: Is this even true? Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},~x\mapsto\exp(-x^2)$. This function takes no global minimum. Or what am I missing?